# Positioning a div element with x and y offset of another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day! With javascript I am trying to create a function which will create a `div` element with a small offset from the triggering button / div. The good news is that at least as much elements are created as much as one of the effects is triggered. The bad news is that the styling of the `X` and `Y` of the div is not working properly.

The code is actually pretty short, I have posted some comments to make it more readable, I don't get any errors when running the function so I really have no idea where the error is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        /*What will be created*/
        .box {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color:red;
            }

        /*The positioning for the first button*/
        .btm12 {
            margin-left:50%;
            margin-top:5%
            }

        /*The positioning for the second button*/
        .btm1 {
            margin-left:30%;
            margin-top:10%
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn" onclick="createBox()" class="btm1">Click me</button><br />
    <button id="btn2" onclick="createBox()" class="btm12">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () { createBox(this.id); };
    document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = function () { createBox(this.id); };

    function createBox(IDI) {
        //get reference to the element
        var element = document.getElementById(IDI); 

        //a way we can acces the X and Y coordinates
        var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        var x = position.left;
        var y = position.top;

        //create, style and set the X/Y of the the div element
        var box = document.createElement("div");
        box.className = "box";
        box.style.left = x;
        box.style.top = y -10;
        box.style.position = "absolute";

        //Apend the element to the body
        document.body.appendChild(box);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i would imagine it's not working because the `<script>` tags are not inside the `<html>` tags. Put the script in the `<head>` element

Comment: Thank you for the input, however this is not the problem. The '<script>' tag doesn't necessarily have to be '<head>' element.

Comment: But they're not inside the `<html>` tags - can you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "px" for your style values when you set them this way. See:

```
    box.style.left = x+"px";
    box.style.top = (y -10)+"px";
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MLmCM/

Comment: That is correct! I will try not to forget adding the pixels this time. Thank you.